# What's the best open-source Java Bayesian spam filter library?

Tags: java, machine-learning, spam-prevention, classification, bayesian

In other answers at Stackoverflow it's been suggested that Weka is good, but there are others ([Classifier4j](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/), [jBNC](http://jbnc.sourceforge.net/), [Naiban](http://www.tempeststrings.com/naiban/)).

Does anyone have actual experience with these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weka is awesome, but [Classifier4J](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/) is probably closer to what you want, since it's more aimed at text recognition.

Comment: Classifier4J hasn't been updated in 5 years!  I am not using that.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have a look at the still very new [Apache Mahout](http://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/index.html#index-Classification) project.

Answer (score 0):

Another new library is [ci-bayes](https://ci-bayes.dev.java.net/), nice and very simple to use.

disclaimer: I have submitted a patches to this project and am currently a committer