# "Learning" filter engines

Tags: filter, search-engine

Are there any "intelligent" or "learning" engines out there, that are able to identify "evil" phrases in texts ( maybe something like a learning Spamfilter... e.g. used in Thunderbird? )

For example if i want to filter texts with mailadresses:

```
asdasd asd as d dgfdgfdgfdg sadasd(at)asfsdf.com
```

At first the tool wouldn't recognize this as an emailadress... but if the user "teached" ( clicked a "text contains an mailadress"-button for example ) the tool several times, that text which contains phrases like "xxxxx(at)xxxxx.xx" is suspicious, it "learns" that it should mark these text automatically in the future...

Question: Is there anything like it on the market? I foudn some libs ( like SpamAssasin, etc. ) but these are "specialized" on emails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this seems to be good start: http://nbayes.codeplex.com/ ( C# implementation of the bayesian algorithm )

Answer (score 2):

The general idea you are talking about is a [Bayesian filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filteringhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering).  Maybe that will help you in your searches.

Edit: A few other examples:

- [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558219/bayesian-spam-filtering-library-for-python)
- [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480683/whats-the-best-open-source-java-bayesian-spam-filter-library)
- [.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516625/is-there-a-bayesian-filter-library-for-net)
- [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080732/implementing-bayesian-classifier-in-ruby)